# command line ipython with --pylab + more imports

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

The `--pylab` command line arguments makes `ipython` a quick but powerful calculator in the terminal window which I use quite often. Is there a way to pass other useful imports to `ipython` via command line, such as

```
from scipy.constants import *
```

which makes it even more convenient to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed `sympy` you get script that starts `ipython` with `sympy` imports.  This script may give you ideas.

```
2119:~/mypy$ which isympy
/usr/local/bin/isympy
2119:~/mypy$ cat /usr/local/bin/isympy
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from isympy import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

There may also be a place in the profile to specify imports, but I haven't explored that recently.

Or use the '-c' option:

```
2128:~/mypy$ ipython3 --pylab -c "from scipy import constants" -i
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg

In [1]: constants.bar
Out[1]: 100000.0
```

Comment: I guess the trick was the `-i` switch at the end. Thanks!